# Import tf in python, in fuerte

Tags: ros-fuerte, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

Probably a dumb question, but I'm not sure how to import tf in Python with fuerte.

I've installed fuerte with the Ubuntu packages.

tf is available in the geometry stack, but it does not seem to install anything in /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.6/dist-packages, so a simple "import tf" does not work (which is what is mention [in the doc](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/tf/html/python/tf_python.html)).

Should I use the old 'manifest + roslib' way?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31158/import-tf-in-python,-in-fuerte/) by [severin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2119/severin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 240 on 2012-04-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [josh_h](https://answers.ros.org/users/4409/josh_h/) on 2013-03-12**:
What is the old way, btw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Only the lower-level libraries have been converted to use the FHS/standard locations.  If it doesn't start with a 'ros' prefix, it probably hasn't been converted.  Only ros, ros_comm, rx, actionlib, and common_msgs were converted.

You still use the old way for tf.  It will likely transition in Groovy.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1